# Why does the struct in this union appear to order itself backwards

Tags: c, struct, bit-manipulation, unions

```
#include <stdio.h>

union bits_32{
    unsigned int x;
    struct {char b4,b3,b2,b1;} byte;
} ;

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    union bits_32 foo;
    foo.x=0x100000FA;
    printf("%x",foo.byte.b4 & 0xFF);
}
```

This will output FA. Why doesn't it output 10 since b4 occupies the first space?

Comment: x86 is little-endian.

Comment: this is because of endianness like others have said. But the compilers may move variables and structure elements to accomodate memory alignment so the result may not the same on all little endian computers. It's best to use an array instead of 4 chars

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, I was just playing around with lower level constructs in preparation for an interview tomorrow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's depends on endianess of your machine. If your machine is little endian it prints FA(Your's is little endian right?). If your machine is big endian it prints 10.

**Storing Words in Memory**
We've defined a word to mean 32 bits. This is the same as 4 bytes. Integers, single-precision floating point numbers, and MIPS instructions are all 32 bits long. How can we store these values into memory? After all, each memory address can store a single byte, not 4 bytes.

The answer is simple. We split the 32 bit quantity into 4 bytes. For example, suppose we have a 32 bit quantity, written as `90AB12CD16`, which is hexadecimal. Since each hex digit is 4 bits, we need 8 hex digits to represent the 32 bit value.

So, the 4 bytes are: `90, AB, 12, CD` where each byte requires 2 hex digits.

It turns out there are two ways to store this in memory.
**Big Endian**
In big endian, you store the most significant byte in the smallest address. Here's how it would look:

```
Address Value
1000    90
1001    AB
1002    12
1003    CD
```

**Little Endian**
In little endian, you store the least significant byte in the smallest address. Here's how it would look:

```
Address Value
1000    CD
1001    12
1002    AB
1003    90
```

Notice that this is in the reverse order compared to big endian. To remember which is which, recall whether the least significant byte is stored first (thus, little endian) or the most significant byte is stored first (thus, big endian).

Notice I used "byte" instead of "bit" in least significant bit. I sometimes abbreciated this as LSB and MSB, with the 'B' capitalized to refer to byte and use the lowercase 'b' to represent bit. I only refer to most and least significant byte when it comes to endianness.

Comment: IIRC x86 is little endian, so yes. I misunderstood how endianness worked so that was the confusion. Thanks.

Comment: (A slight correction: in addition to little and big endian, there are also various "middle endian" possibilities for storing words of more than two bytes. C permits them, so there are more than "two ways".)

Comment: @Arkku Yes I agree. If you have data regarding that edit my post and add it. Thanks